# Pandas doesn't separate string in csv file to columns correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am new to data analysis on Python and faced with problem in project making process. Some of the values in csv file has a delimiter in the double quotes, so Pandas can't separate it correctly

```
top = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\data analytics\Project\Analysis-Spotify-Top-2000\Spotify-2000.csv",delimiter = ",",
        encoding = "UTF-8", doublequote=True, engine="python", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

I found which records calls that problem:

[image: screen1]

My teacher advice me to create a new dataframe with these values and the same columns, and those records that has a delimiter in double quotes should be deleted, then the df will merge to the original.

But honestly, I don't know how to do it properly (I made some weird things - [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdxed.png))

```
is_title_null = pd.isnull(top["Title"])
missing_list = top[is_title_null]["Index"].tolist()
list_of_missing_list = []
for i in missing_list:
l = i.split(', ')
list_of_missing_list.append(l)
list_of_missing_list
missing_df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((0, 15)))    
missing_df.columns = ["Index", "Title","Artist","Top Genre","Year","Beats Per Minute 
(BPM)","Energy","Danceability","Loudness (dB)","Liveness","Valence","Length 
(Duration)","Acousticness","Speechiness","Popularity"]
 missing_df.append(list_of_missing_list,ignore_index = True)
```

Here is my project link in GitHub (here you can see the problem): https://github.com/Sabina-Karenkina/Analysis-Spotify-Top-2000

Comment: Please fix code indentation _and_ add a fragment of the CSV file (not a screenshot, but a properly formatted text fragment).

Comment: I downloaded the csv file and all the rows that present the error you show unfortunately start with " (ex:  "49,""You're The First, The Last, My Everything"",Barry White,adult standards,2009,131,72,64,-7,14,80,213,1,4,67"  . This implies that the error cannot be corrected after import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This is not a really elegant way to do things, but as I mentioned in the comment I made previously you will not fix the problem by first creating the dataframe because the file is corrupt to begin with. I managed to find a way to easily solve it.

Open your `Spotify-2000`-file with excel and make text to columns. When asked which delimiter, choose , (comma). Save your file as a new ´´´csv´´´-file (Soptify2.csv) but make sure to have ; as delimiter (this is because you might have titles including commas.

Now, use `pandas` to read this new file:

```
top = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/k_sego/spotify2.csv",delimiter = ";",
        encoding = "iso-8859-1", doublequote=True, engine="python")
top.head(100)
```

[image]